# how to create views dynamically in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i have an advertisement site written with `laravel` , in it users can create there own page using the MCE `tinymce` i provided for them , and below it : is the name of the page , my question is how can i create the new view, based on there input name for example : survialence_cameras ( is the name that user has chosen for his/her page ) . now how do i create a page ( view ) with the same name that customer inserted, so his/her address would be: `www.example.com/survialence_cameras`

Comment: `/survialence_cameras` would be a slug to the page. The rest you would be filling in the template with the users content. Much like a CMS / Wiki etc.. You dont create views per user.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for your answer , i'm a beginner , actually i didn't get what was your meaning exactly ! you mean i can't do it ? its not my decision , my boss wants it , and i should do it for him , even if its not a good idea

Comment: tinymce is not going to give you the flexibility you need to make views anyway, also if you give too much your end up with a site full of XSS exploits, you would need to make a CMS / Wiki / Profile style system, where your users can input content into predefined or dynamically added *sections/widgets*, your boss might want it, but bosses are almost always ignorant to the problems code monkeys need to deal with to deliver a safe usable product.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer, for anyone that has the same question, just write below code in your web.php file

```
Route::get( 'sites/{keyword}', function ( $keyword) {
    fopen( resource_path( 'views/' . $keyword . '.blade.php' ), 'w' );
    return view(  $keyword   );
});
```

also, you can always save tinymce values in a variable and store it in your database, to know how it works just take a look at this video friends videos, it is very useful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-SvIFS4J8o

Comment: this peace of code can threat your site security . little hint : validate $keyword first  then check if the file exists or not

Comment: seems like you didn't get the meaning of the code , it creates the file , and if there is no keyword , no file would be created. the porpuse of this code is to create pages dynamically, although there are some other ways too .